# PHP Dynamic Variable Names in Between Words

Tags: php, dynamic, dynamic-variables

I have a badly designed Database that I have to deal with. In order to have a smaller code footprint, I need to use dynamic variable naming in PHP. However, the names of each variable vary greatly. Here's a sample of my code:

```
<?php

    $test = (object)[
        'variable_1_text'   => 'ONE',
        'variablevv_1_another_one'   => 'Two',
        'variablett_1_blah'   => 'III',
        'variablex_1_text_lala'   => 'Four',
        'variable_2_text'   => 'ONE',
        'variablevv_2_another_one'   => 'Two',
        'variablett_2_blah'   => 'III',
        'variablex_2_text_lala'   => 'Four',
        'variable_3_text'   => 'ONE',
        'variablevv_3_another_one'   => 'Two',
        'variablett_3_blah'   => 'III',
        'variablex_3_text_lala'   => 'Four',
        'variable_4_text'   => 'ONE',
        'variablevv_4_another_one'   => 'Two',
        'variablett_4_blah'   => 'III',
        'variablex_4_text_lala'   => 'Four',
    ];

    //this doesn't work
    foreach (array(1,2,3,4) as $temp_val) {
        echo $test->variable_{$temp_val}_text . "<br />";
        echo $test->variablevv_{$temp_val}_another_one . "<br />";
        echo $test->variablett_{$temp_val}_blah . "<br />";
        echo $test->variablex_{$temp_val}_text_lala . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

There's a lot of these variables. I just need how to dynamically make those 1, 2, 3, and 4 in between the names of the variable names. Is this even possible?

Comment: use curly braces to access such object properties

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. I tried using curly braces in my sample code above but that doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
`$test->{'variable_'.$temp_val.'_text'};`

Comment: Hi FoxVSky, but this would let me change all of the variable names. Like the word 'variable_' and '_text' varies from all of the variables. I only need to dynamically concatenate the 1, 2, 3, and 4 in the existing variable names.